# Which function to use to validate - input year should not be greater than the current year

Tags: pega

I have a requirement where the input year should not be greater than the current year. This validation has to be given to the field... (using Integer input field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well no such out of the box function present in `Pega`.

You need to write it on your own.
If you are looking for `Edit Validate` rule then you can write an edit validate rule with below code.

```
    if (theValue.trim().length() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
// theValue is by default the value present on the field. Its String by default.
    int year = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR); // get the current year value.
    
    if (Integer.parseInt(theValue) < year){ //convert theValue to int and check if it is less than the current year.
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
```

You can write a `java function` also and call it in `Obj Validate` rule. If you want to chose the `java function` option instead of `edit validate` then that function should accept `theValue` as parameter.